# Descriptografar XML com senha privada do certificado digital

Tags: c#, xml, criptografia

Preciso descriptografar este XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xenc:EncryptedData
        xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
        Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element">
<xenc:EncryptionMethod
        Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" />
<ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:X509Data>
        <ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Certificate>
    </ds:X509Data>
    <xenc:EncryptedKey
            xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <xenc:EncryptionMethod
                Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
        <xenc:CipherData>
            <xenc:CipherValue></xenc:CipherValue>
        </xenc:CipherData>
    </xenc:EncryptedKey>
</ds:KeyInfo>
<xenc:CipherData>
    <xenc:CipherValue></xenc:CipherValue>
</xenc:CipherData>
```

Este é o meu projeto que estou executando:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.Xml;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    // Create an XmlDocument object.
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

    string arquivoXML = "C:\\Teste-Desc\\1-23042015-0703-ACE58971ACE59070.xml";
    string thumbPrintCertificado = "BA71F3AA888E0197D945D2A0CDE21C7E694CE432";


    // Load an XML file into the XmlDocument object. 
    try
    {
        xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
        xmlDoc.Load(arquivoXML);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

    // Create a new TripleDES key. 
    TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tDESkey = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    X509Certificate2 cert = BuscaConfiguracaoCertificado(thumbPrintCertificado);
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;

    try
    {            
        Decrypt(xmlDoc, rsaKey);


        // Display the encrypted XML to the console.
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Decrypted XML:");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(xmlDoc.OuterXml);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        // Clear the TripleDES key.
        tDESkey.Clear();
    }

}

public static void Encrypt(XmlDocument Doc, string ElementToEncrypt, TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider Alg)
{

    //////////////////////////////////////////////// 
    // Find the specified element in the XmlDocument 
    // object and create a new XmlElemnt object. 
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////

    XmlElement elementToEncrypt = Doc.GetElementsByTagName(ElementToEncrypt)[0] as XmlElement;

    // Throw an XmlException if the element was not found. 
    if (elementToEncrypt == null)
    {
        throw new XmlException("The specified element was not found");

    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
    // Create a new instance of the EncryptedXml class  
    // and use it to encrypt the XmlElement with the  
    // symmetric key. 
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////

    EncryptedXml eXml = new EncryptedXml();

    byte[] encryptedElement = eXml.EncryptData(elementToEncrypt, Alg, false);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////// 
    // Construct an EncryptedData object and populate 
    // it with the desired encryption information. 
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////


    EncryptedData edElement = new EncryptedData();

    edElement.Type = EncryptedXml.XmlEncElementUrl;


    // Create an EncryptionMethod element so that the  
    // receiver knows which algorithm to use for decryption. 
    // Determine what kind of algorithm is being used and 
    // supply the appropriate URL to the EncryptionMethod element.

    edElement.EncryptionMethod = new EncryptionMethod(EncryptedXml.XmlEncTripleDESUrl);

    // Add the encrypted element data to the  
    // EncryptedData object.
    edElement.CipherData.CipherValue = encryptedElement;

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
    // Replace the element from the original XmlDocument 
    // object with the EncryptedData element. 
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    EncryptedXml.ReplaceElement(elementToEncrypt, edElement, false);

}

public static void Decrypt(XmlDocument Doc, RSA Alg)
{
    // Check the arguments.
    if (Doc == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Doc");
    if (Alg == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Alg");

    // Create a new EncryptedXml object.
    EncryptedXml exml = new EncryptedXml(Doc);

    // Add a key-name mapping.
    // This method can only decrypt documents
    // that present the specified key name.
    exml.AddKeyNameMapping("rsaKey", Alg);

    // Decrypt the element.
    exml.DecryptDocument();

}

public static X509Certificate2 BuscaConfiguracaoCertificado(string sDigitalThumbPrint)
{
    X509Certificate2 x509Cert = null;

    X509Store store = new X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
    X509Certificate2Collection collection = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;
    X509Certificate2Collection collection1 = null;
    collection1 = (X509Certificate2Collection)collection.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, sDigitalThumbPrint, false);

    for (int i = 0; i < collection1.Count; i++)
    {
        x509Cert = collection1[i];
    }

    return x509Cert;
}
```

}

Mas quando chega no ponto:

```
exml.DecryptDocument();
```

Gera a seguinte exceção:
Não é possível recuperar a chave de descriptografia.

Segundo manual do TJMG devo utilizar a chave privada do Certificado digital do cliente...

Já não sei mais o que fazer, gratifico se alguém puder me ajudar...

Comment: Qual a classe da exceção? (e de preferência, o *stack trace*, pra gente saber *exatamente* qual método a lançou) Eu não entendo de encriptação XML, mas se souber mais detalhes da exceção posso ver se encontro algo pra te ajudar a determinar a causa do erro. A propósito, você *tem* a chave privada do Certificado digital do cliente, não tem? Quem encriptou esse documento?

Comment: O TJMG quem gera o XML, ele utiliza a chave pública do certificado do cliente para criptografa-lo, agora tenho que usar a privada para descripotgrafar...
Sobre como funciona...
http://selos.tjmg.jus.br/desenvolvedor/solicitacao-selos.html
A exceção e o ponto eu coloquei nas ultimas linhas..

Comment: "A exceção e o ponto eu coloquei nas ultimas linhas.." onde? Não estou vendo, na pergunta só fala "Gera a seguinte exceção: Não é possível recuperar a chave de descriptografia." Eu entendi que é aquela linha de código que não funciona, mas para saber onde a exceção se *originou*, só com o *stack trace*. A classe da exceção também ajuda na hora de pesquisar por uma solução. (a propósito, o texto da exceção está assim mesmo, em português?)

Comment: Acabei de perceber aqui que o seu XML especifica o algoritmo de criptografia como AES256-CBC, mas você está tentando decifrá-lo usando 3DES...

Answer (score 1):

> Resposta parcial

Não tenho uma resposta pra sua pergunta, mas lendo [a documentação citada](http://selos.tjmg.jus.br/desenvolvedor/solicitacao-selos.html) posso ver o que você está fazendo de errado (o que é um primeiro passo pra consertar). Não sei utilizar esse tipo de criptografia em C# (aliás, em linguagem nenhuma) entretanto, por isso vou apenas explicar o que está acontecendo de modo a te orientar na busca de uma solução:

1. Seu documento está cifrado usando o AES 256, modo CBC, um tipo de criptografia **simétrica**:

```
    <xenc:EncryptionMethod
            Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" />
```

2. A chave de criptografia (que, sendo simétrica, serve tanto pra cifrar quanto pra decifrar) está contida no próprio documento:

   ```
   <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
       ...
       <xenc:EncryptedKey
       xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
           ...
           <xenc:CipherData>
               <xenc:CipherValue></xenc:CipherValue>
           </xenc:CipherData>
       </xenc:EncryptedKey>
   </ds:KeyInfo>
   ```

   ...mas não no formato plano (claro, pois assim qualquer um poderia decifrar!): ela foi cifrada usando uma outra chave - uma **chave cifradora de chaves** (*key-encription key* - KEK).

   ```
   <xenc:EncryptionMethod
           Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
   ```

   Como você mesmo apontou, ela foi cifrada com a chave pública do certificado do cliente (RSA 1.5), exigindo portanto a chave privada correspondente para decifrar.

O código Java mostrado como referência está executando essas operações corretamente. Comentando:

```java
// Obtém uma instância da cifra RSA 1.5 (para a KEK)
cipher = XMLCipher.getInstance(XMLCipher.RSA_v1dot5);

// Referencia o elemento que contém o item criptografado
Element ee = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("xenc:EncryptedData").item(0);

// Obtém uma instância da cifra AES 256 (para os dados de fato)
// Estou assumindo que o modo CBC é o modo padrão, quando um não é especificado
cipher = XMLCipher.getInstance(XMLCipher.AES_256);

// Inicializa
cipher.init(XMLCipher.DECRYPT_MODE, null);

// Atribui a chave cifradora de chaves
cipher.setKEK(rsaKey);

// Faz todas as operações necessárias, nos elementos corretos
// - Decifra a chave AES usando a chave RSA fornecida
// - Decifra os dados usando a chave AES decifrada
return cipher.doFinal(doc, ee);
```

É necessário portanto executar essas mesmas operações no C#. Acredito (mas não posso confirmar pela experiência) que esse [*"How to"*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229919%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) implementa todos os passos necessários:

```cs
    CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
    cspParams.KeyContainerName = "XML_ENC_RSA_KEY";

    // Get the RSA key from the key container.  This key will decrypt 
    // a symmetric key that was imbedded in the XML document.
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);

    try
    {
        // Decrypt the elements.
        Decrypt(xmlDoc, rsaKey, "rsaKey");

        // Save the XML document.
        xmlDoc.Save("test.xml");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        // Clear the RSA key.
        rsaKey.Clear();
    }
```

(O `Decrypt` é o mesmo que você já está fazendo)

Não posso garantir que isso vai resolver seu problema (como achar essa chave na *key store*, isso é algo que não tenho ideia de como funciona), mas já é um passo na direção certa.